# How to use execute loop for 3 times in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python3 .Below is the basic program. Here I want to restrict the numbers of re-try to 3 times. How can I achieve in Python. Thanks in Advance.

```
def add(x,y):
    return x +y
def sub(x,y):
    return x -y    
def mul(x,y):
    return x *y
def div(x,y):
    return x /y

print("Select Operation from below:")
print("1.Addition")
print("2.Subtraction")
print("3.Multiplication")
print("4.Division")

while True:
    choice= int(input("Enter your Choice(1,2,3,4)  from above:"))
    if choice in (1,2,3,4):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number :"))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number :"))
        if choice == 1:
            print("Addition of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,add(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Subtraction of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,sub(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Multiplication of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,mul(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 4:
            print("Division of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,div(num1,num2)))
        break
    else:
        invalidCount =0
        if invalidCount <=3:
            invalidCount += 1 
            print("Invalid Input with retry no {}".format(invalidCount))
        else:
            print("Exceeded maximum number of Invalid re-try")
```

Comment: You should define `invalidCount` in  the `while` loop scope so you can check if it reaches 3, you `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of the loop when you exceed the retries like below:

```
....
else:
   print("Exceeded maximum number of Invalid re-try")  
   break##This will ensure you break from the immediate loop like while in your case.
```

The problem in your code is, everytime you are resetting the `invalidCount` to 0 when user inputs an invalid input. You should initialize that variable outside of the loop.

Another way to look at that would be, to fix the while condition itself to something like:

```
invalidCount = 0
while invalidCount <= 3:
```

And then in the `else` part you just increment the `invalidCount` which would make your code a bit clean and concise.

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the variable `invalidCount`. You'll want to put `invalidCount =0` before the loop. You're also not breaking from the loop when there are too many attempts. With those two changes, it'd look like:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x +y
def sub(x,y):
    return x -y    
def mul(x,y):
    return x *y
def div(x,y):
    return x /y

print("Select Operation from below:")
print("1.Addition")
print("2.Subtraction")
print("3.Multiplication")
print("4.Division")

invalidCount = 0

while True:
    choice= int(input("Enter your Choice(1,2,3,4)  from above:"))
    if choice in (1,2,3,4):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number :"))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number :"))
        if choice == 1:
            print("Addition of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,add(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Subtraction of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,sub(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Multiplication of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,mul(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 4:
            print("Division of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,div(num1,num2)))
        break
    else:
        if invalidCount <=3:
            invalidCount += 1 
            print("Invalid Input with retry no {}".format(invalidCount))
        else:
            print("Exceeded maximum number of Invalid re-try")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your current code:

1. You need to declare the `invalidCount` object outside of the `while` loop
2. You are missing the `break` statement to come out of loop

Try this:

```
invalidCount =0
while True:
    choice= int(input("Enter your Choice(1,2,3,4)  from above:"))
    if choice in (1,2,3,4):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number :"))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number :"))
        if choice == 1:
            print("Addition of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,add(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Subtraction of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,sub(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Multiplication of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,mul(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 4:
            print("Division of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,div(num1,num2)))
        break
    else:
        if invalidCount <=3:
            invalidCount += 1 
            print("Invalid Input with retry no {}".format(invalidCount))
        else:
            print("Exceeded maximum number of Invalid re-try")
            break
```

Comment: Awesome, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(x,y):
    return x +y
def sub(x,y):
    return x -y    
def mul(x,y):
    return x *y
def div(x,y):
    return x /y

invalidCount =0

print("Select Operation from below:")
print("1.Addition")
print("2.Subtraction")
print("3.Multiplication")
print("4.Division")

while True:
    choice= int(input("Enter your Choice(1,2,3,4)  from above:"))
    if choice in (1,2,3,4):
        invalidCount =0 # This line is that if after some invalid tries if user makes a valid tries then the invalid tries are reset remove this line if you want that number of invalid tries to be fixed
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number :"))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number :"))
        if choice == 1:
            print("Addition of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,add(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Subtraction of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,sub(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Multiplication of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,mul(num1,num2)))
        elif choice == 4:
            print("Division of 2 numbers {} and  {} is {} ".format(num1,num2,div(num1,num2)))
        break
    else:
        if invalidCount <=3:
            invalidCount += 1 
            print("Invalid Input with retry no {}".format(invalidCount))
        else:
            print("Exceeded maximum number of Invalid re-try")  
            break
```